# xampp apache and mysql not running...not a port problem....how to fix

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

My apache is not running, and also sometimes mysql. the error says its something with ssl certificate and VCRUNTIME140.dll.

This is the error in apache
[image]

the error log in apache
[image]

mysql error...this occurs sometimes
[image]

error log of mysql
[image]

I already tried reinstalling the xampp. all of the version from 7.4 to latest. the same error still occurs. but when I tried version 7.3 there is no error but the problem is I need a higher version to use phpspreadsheet, it says that it should be atleast 7.4. my composer is 8 but I can reinstall a lower version but the problem is phpspreadsheet which I need

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you uninstall all Microsoft Visual C++ 20XX libraries inside your computer and reinstall them afterwards (both the 32 and 64 bits versions). You can download all of them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Some of them are for old versions of Xampp package, but don't worry: they will not cause any harm to you computer.